# Accessing Web cam with dart

Tags: html, webcam, dart

Is there a way I can access the webcam on the computer with dart. I have tried the documentation and reading through the blogs but it seems that no one has ever asked this before.

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 4):

Accessing the cam is not necessarily a Dart-specific question but rather if there's is a corresponding **HTML5 API which is accessible through Dart**.

[MediaStream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_html/MediaStream.html) and [LocalMediaStream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_html/LocalMediaStream.html) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with no success:

```
VideoElement webcamVideo = query('#webcamVideo');
window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({'video': true}, (e) { 
    print(e);
    webcamVideo.src = new DOMURL().createObjectURL(e);
});
```

The problem is that in Dart SDK version 10311, createObjectURL() is conspicuously missing from DOMURL interface, although it is available in _DOMURLImpl (edit: as static method).

Comment: Thanks, please star this bug: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4231

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help accessing webcam using Flutter/Dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class WebCam extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebCam({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebCamState createState() => _WebCamState();
}

class _WebCamState extends State<WebCam> {
  // Webcam widget to insert into the tree
  late Widget _webcamWidget;
  // VideoElement
  late VideoElement _webcamVideoElement;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Create a video element which will be provided with stream source
    _webcamVideoElement = VideoElement();
    // Register an webcam
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'webcamVideoElement', (int viewId) => _webcamVideoElement);
    // Create video widget
    _webcamWidget =
        HtmlElementView(key: UniqueKey(), viewType: 'webcamVideoElement');
    // Access the webcam stream
    window.navigator.getUserMedia(video: true).then((MediaStream stream) {
      _webcamVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Webcam MediaStream:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
              Container(width: 750, height: 750, child: _webcamWidget),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(_webcamVideoElement.srcObject!.active!);
          if (_webcamVideoElement.srcObject!.active!) {
            _webcamVideoElement.play();
          } else {
            _webcamVideoElement.pause();
          }
        },
        tooltip: 'Start stream, stop stream',
        child: Icon(Icons.play_circle),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```